# How can we create our own private TOR circuit?

Tags: private

For one of my project, I want to create a private TOR network and want to send my traffic through that but I am unable to create it. Can anyone suggest how it can be done?

Comment: any specification or manual would greatly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tor's manpage (also available as the [Tor manual](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en)) already has everything you need. You probably want the TestingTorNetwork option along with DirAuthority. Also see [Chutney](https://gitweb.torproject.org/chutney.git/), a way to run a testing Tor network automatically.

Comment: I have done it :)